# Storing the link prediction score in a matrix form using networkx

Tags: networkx, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to store the adamic adar link prediction score from networkx in a matrix form by following way.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([('a','b'),('b','c'),('a','d'),('c','d'),('b','d')])
preds = nx.adamic_adar_index(G, ebunch = G.edges())

B = nx.Graph()
for u,v,p in preds:
   B.add_edge(u,v,weight=p)

Adj_mat = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(B)
```

But this way is very slow in my case for `2,858,219` edges. Is their any faster way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

## Profiling the job

You can use the python `cProfiler` to observe the bottleneck in your job:

```
cProfile.run('''
G = nx.complete_graph(100)
preds = nx.adamic_adar_index(G, ebunch = G.edges())

B = nx.Graph()
for u,v,p in preds:
   B.add_edge(u,v,weight=p)

Adj_mat = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(B)
''')
```

## Analysis

From this analysis, you can observe that a significant portion of time is spent on `link_prediction.py:199(predict)` which is the core algorithm of `adamic_adar_index()`. Thus you may have to implement a more efficient version of the algorithm yourself.